# TinyMCE with IMCE image uploading in Drupal 6 doesn't replace [img] tag with actual image

Tags: drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

My site runs Drupal 6. Users need a comfortable way to insert images in their posts.
I have the following relevant modules: WYSIWYG, TinyMCE, IMCE and IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge. IMCE works just fine for browsing and uploading images; it then inserts a [img]/path/[/img] into the post.

When viewing the node, both as administrator or anonymous user, this tag is displayed as plain text, not as the image we want. The input format of the node is Full HTML, I also added the [img] tag to allowed tags - no difference.
I also searched the IMCE issue queue, but there's no mention of this problem.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Update: the Image Assist module must be installed and enabled for inline images to work. This module translates the [img] tags to actual html. The Image Assist filter must also be enabled on the Full HTML input format, under filters.

I did this, but still no image showing up.

Comment: As it turns out, the weight of the filters in the Full HTML input format is important. All my filters had the same weight. I rearranged them, setting the "Inline images" filter last - and now it works! Huzzah!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Answer your own question with the solution you found. Maybe someone will upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

The Image Assist module must be installed and enabled for inline images to work. This module translates the [img] tags to actual html. The Image Assist filter must also be enabled on the Full HTML input format, under filters. 
You must also check the weight of the filters in the Full HTML input format is important. All my filters had the same weight. I rearranged them, setting the "Inline images" filter last - and now it works!